# send a speech to text output directly to database with json

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

i am trying to build a modern IVR with attention word recognition:and i encountered the following challenge. i was trying to save the output from a speech recognition and send that data directly to database in another server using json.so here are my 2 questions.

1. How can i generate  json file for that output and give that output value to the intended key.

2.since its going to be a question and answer type dialog between the customer and the system,how can i save all answers to that json file for every word recognition

Comment: Have you read this ? https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

Comment: yes.but i haven't found anything useful to my project. i am not using google speech recognition for my project. so i am building my own rest api.

Comment: There are many services speech to text API Rest....the problem is the cost?

Comment: yes. So i have to build the rest api myself. can you please help me build this